# newbie : Ruby programming for factorials

Tags: ruby, math

So I got this question as an assignment in Computer class and I literally have no idea why the solution was such. I am hoping someone can explain it thoroughly to me.

My problem is:

1. How does one know that `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1` is actually just the math expression n! Is this just a magical formula that I have to remember? (Yes, I don't know much math beyond arithmetic)
2. Is there a better way of programming factorials

> Write a method that takes an integer `n` in; it should return
>   `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1`. Assume `n >= 0`.
>
> As a special case, `factorial(0) == 1`.
>
> Difficulty: easy.

```
def factorial(n)
  if n < 0
    return nil
  end

  result = 1
  while n > 0
    result = result * n

    n -= 1
  end

  return result
end


puts("factorial(0) == 1: #{factorial(0) == 1}")
puts("factorial(1) == 1: #{factorial(1) == 1}")
puts("factorial(2) == 2: #{factorial(2) == 2}")
puts("factorial(3) == 6: #{factorial(3) == 6}")
puts("factorial(4) == 24: #{factorial(4) == 24}")
```

Comment: What part are you exactly wanting to be explained? The while loop?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague because doesn't ask about a specific issue. Could you clarify what exactly you don't understand about the solution?

Comment: The definition of a factorial is literally "the product of numbers 1 to n". It's not a magical formula, it's just what a factorial is.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think my problem is I don't know why the teacher used the expression: n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1 instead of just saying n! OR JUST saying N factorial. it will be something I will just have to learn. when I did understand that is what they wanted. I understand the while loop. Thanks Amadan for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that is the definition of a factorial. One knows it by having learned the definition.
2. There are many ways to code up a factorial. Yours happens to be the most basic one. As you learn more about Ruby, you will start to be able to write more idiomatic code. For example...

   ```
   def factorial_functional(n)
     n < 0 ? nil : (1..n).inject(1, &:*)
   end

   def factorial_recursive(n)
     return if n < 0
     return 1 if n == 0
     n * factorial_recursive(n - 1)
   end
   ```

   It is arguable what is "better", since there are so many factors: readability, conciseness, speed, memory usage... And readability is directly related to the target audience: I'm sure your code is more readable to you than either of my examples, but to someone experienced it is much more of a hassle to go through your longer code.

Comment: I'd say that the recursive solution is likely what the instructor is looking for.  Any time I've ever seen factorials in a programming class it is always to create a situation where recursion is an efficient answer.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I doubt it, as the task description states the unrolled definition. In a mathematics class you might be expected to make the jump from `n! = n * (n - 1) * ... * 2 * 1` to `1! = 0, n! = n * (n - 1)! for n > 1`; but such a jump should not be required for a computing class (even if it is the most basic application of mathematic induction possible).

Answer (score 0):

Amadan already showed better ways of writing the `factorials` method, but I believe you were also asking for an explanation of the solution you brought in.

```
# The method `factorial` receives a number `n` and returns `n!`.
def factorial(n)
  if n < 0               # If the number `n` is negative
    return nil           # `n!` can't be calculated, so return nothing.
  end                    # Otherwise, go on...

  result = 1             # `result` is 1. For now...
  while n > 0            # While the number `n` is positive
    result = result * n  # `result` becomes `result` times `n`.
    n -= 1               # Decrease the number `n` by one.
  end
                         # Once the number `n` becomes zero, `result` is
                         # equal to the multiplication of all numbers from 1
                         # to what `n` was at the very beginning.
  return result          # Return `result`
end
```

I would also like to contribute the following "better" way of defining the `factorial` method that can be read, more or less, in plain English:

```
def factorial(number)
  return unless number.is_a? Integer and number >= 0

  total = 1

  number.downto 1 do |this_number|   
    total = total * this_number
  end

  return total
end
```